# I want to show news detail . detail.php page but it does not picking the id in detail.php page .in detail.php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to show news detail . detail.php page but it does not picking the id in detail.php page .in detail.php page i have write query for select the id but in id what i should place?

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

 echo  '<li><a href="detail.php?'.$row["news_id"].'">';
 echo  $row["title"];
 echo  '</a></li>';
}
```

Comment: *"I want to show pictures from mysql db"* - if you want to show pictures (images), you need to use the `<img>` tag, if that's what the question's about. Or what data type it is for the image column in question.

Comment: *"but it does not picking the id in detail.php page"* - Did you select it in the query? Your question's pretty unclear, IMHO.

Comment: Look i have two pages Like i have news_ticker bar in my main news page . there is moving news and there must be link inside each news for further details. i want to show when someone click on the moving news link the detail page will be open

Comment: When you are building the URL behind Hyperlink (your detail.php? etc), you usually build a GET variable name and then put an '=', then provide the id value. like detail.php?news_id=44 . In the detail.php, use the GET array to get the value of news_id, then send it to the database and fetch and show whatever you want. In your detail.php? URL above, there is no GET variable name, followed by value.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get the id in your `detail.php` if you don't give a name for your query string parameter.

Try this :

```
<?php
echo  '<li><a href="detail.php?id='.$row["news_id"].'">';
```

And in `detail.php` you can get the `id` like this: `$id = $_GET['id']`

Comment: Yes its working http://localhost/abc/admin/pages/publish/detail.php?id=103   i want to show like this http://localhost.com/news/43888.html means i don't want to show there should bhi id include in link

Comment: You can take a look for url rewriting according to your web server.
What king of server are you using ? Apache ? Nginx ?

Comment: am using apache server now

Comment: You are amazing just please tell me how i do as i am using apache server

Comment: ? hello bobo_dev

Comment: You can put this line in an .htaccess :

`RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)\.html$ /admin/pages/publish/detail.php?id=$1 [L]`

Make sure that the `mod_rewrite` apache module are well enabled by issuing this command in your server: `sudo a2enmod rewrite`

Comment: i am chaning the structure of all. thanks for help. when i done i will come to you if i see there is something else in it